# Why are my products not getting added to the cart?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a django s=online store website. when clicking on add to cart, the products are not being displayed on the cart.

my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect
from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse


def cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    context = {"cart":cart}
    template = 'shopping_cart/cart.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def add_to_cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    if not Product in cart.Products.all():
        cart.products.add(Product)

    else:
        cart.products.remove(Product)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
```

my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product


class Cart(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Cart"
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from products import views
from shopping_cart import views as sc_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', sc_views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('cart/', sc_views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    path('', include('products.urls'))
]
```

my products' models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
```

Comment: You use the same path (`'cart/'`) two times in `urlpatterns`. BTW, do you really work with the outdated Python 2? If not you can remove `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Comment: After you fixed your `urlpatterns` there's another issue. You don't deliver a product to `add_to_cart`. In `add_to_cart` you ask if the class `Product` is an instance of a specific product and that doesn't make sense.